# Wireless and Wired networks don't work

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have this issue with my Ubuntu budgie 20.04 which both wired and wireless networks don't work any more. I had this problem with wireless before and I reinstalled the os to fix it! It worked fine for a month but slowly the wireless network got disabled in middle of work and now after many restarts and shutdowns, it may work for 1 minute! today the same is happening with the wired connection but The odd thing is that the problem is only with the Ethernet cable connection and when I use usb and my mobile usb tethering option, my laptops internet works fine! I don't know whether it is software or hardware and after many searches and command I couldn't figure out the problem. Please help!

```
farzin@farzin-X541UVK:~$ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: What is the hardware?

Comment: @Pilot6 what details do yo need?

Answer (score -2):

Try resetting the root password, this is only a temporary fix lmfao, read my post and you'll know why, reset the password and it'll work for a few days atleast

Comment: what post are you referring to?